# Custom registration function not working as it should because is_mail and email_exist keep giving errors when it shouldn't

Tags: user-registration, email-verification

Here is my registration function

```
    $firstname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['firstname'] );
    $lastname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['lastname'] );
    $username = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg-username'] );
    $user_pass = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['reg-password'] );
    $pass_confirm = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['confirm_password'] );
    $gender = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gender'] );
    $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['email'] );
    //Add usernames we don't want used
    $invalid_usernames = array( 'admin' );
    $errors = array();
    //Do username validation
    $username = sanitize_user( $username );
    if ( empty( $username ) || validate_username( $username ) === false || in_array( $username, $invalid_usernames ) === false ) {
        $errors[]= 'Username is invalid.';
    }
    if ( username_exists( $username ) === false) {
        $errors[]= 'Username already exists.';
    }
    //Do e-mail address validation
    if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'E-mail address is invalid.';
    }
    if (email_exists($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'E-mail address is already in use.';
    }
    if ($user_pass != $pass_confirm) {
        $errors[] = 'Password combination incorrect.';
    }
    $genders = array('male','female',true);
    if ( in_array( $gender,$genders )  === false){
        $errors[] = 'Invalid gender';
    }

    //Everything has been validated, proceed with creating the user

    //Create the user
    if(!empty($errors)):
        wp_send_json_error($errors);
    endif;

    //$user_pass = wp_generate_password();
    $user = array(
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $user_pass,
        'first_name' => $firstname,
        'last_name' => $lastname,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'gender' => $gender
        );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $user );

    /*Send e-mail to admin and new user - 
    You could create your own e-mail instead of using this function*/
    wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $user_pass );
    wp_send_json_success($user_id);
```

I keep getting this error each time.
     `0:"Username is invalid."`
     `1:"Username already exists."`
      `2:"E-mail address is invalid."`
      `3:"E-mail address is already in use."`
      `4:"Invalid gender"` even when all inputs are correct

The password confirmation function is not working even if password combination is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is context lacking I'm not able to fix all your problems. One of the mistakes I see is that in your code this line:

```
if (email_exists($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'E-mail address is already in use.';
}
```

Must be:

```
if(email_exists($email)){ etc.
```

Because you check whether the email_exists function returns an ID when it exists (translates in true) or does not exist, which will give false. Could you give more context (e.g. the form in HTML) for the rest of your question?

EDIT: you make the same mistake with `username_exists($username) === false` which should just be `if(username_exists($username))` instead. Same logic applies.

EDIT EDIT: oh, actually you do that mistake more. Also with `in_array( $username, $invalid_usernames ) === false` must be: `in_array( $username, $invalid_usernames )` Now you are checking the exact opposite of what you want to check I suppose.

Comment: I am still getting this two error (2) `["Username is invalid.", "E-mail address is invalid."]`

Comment: Yes, and I actually also think to know why that is the case. You sanitize your inputs with `sanitize_text_field`. However, this is 'to strict' for e-mails. Instead, for the e-mail address sanitation use `sanitize_email` instead. Here is a link which explains it better: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_email

Comment: I just did but still getting invalid email response

Comment: the one that borders me most is `username_exists( $username )` I used an existing username but it didn't through an error after the adjustment you asked me to do.

Comment: Could you print the sanitized variables and not sanitized POST fields here? Might be due to sanitation. Also, instead of doing `$errors[] = 'error message'` try using something like `array_push` instead. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php .

Comment: Wow thanks it's actually empty but don't know why and this is the url_encoded string after submitting the form

Comment: `redirect_to=%2Fss%2Flogin%2F&firstname=hola&lastname=hola&email=hello%40email.com&reg-username=dev&reg-password=lol&confirm_password=lll&gender=male`

Comment: thanks alot printing the `$_POST` made me realized there were only two variable in the array which was as a result of how I sent the data using jquery.
I really appreciate your effort thanks again.